# collectionview cell dynamic width breaks layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When i try to give a collection view's cell a dynamic with, based on the label it will contain, something strange is happening to the spacing between the cell:

[image]

If i space the items giving a static width, the cell are being layed out as expected:

[image]

The code which gives the item a width is:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout!,
    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGSize
{
    let element = self.default_categories[indexPath.row] as NSString
    let stringSize = element.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18.0)]) 
    // return CGSize(width: stringSize.width, height: self.categoriesView.frame.height)
    return CGSize(width: 100, height: self.categoriesView.frame.height)
}
```

So, basically, i don't really know where that space is coming from, when i 
try to give the cells, a dynamic width.

The sectionInset is (0, 0, 0, 0) and the minimumLineSpacing is also 0.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: fk2blow: @JohnSaunders is correct here. Please read the link he posted. Your argumentative comments didn't "help the community" either, yet you posted them.

Answer (score 1):

The issues was with "minimumInteritemSpacing" property of the layout. Setting it to 0 does remove the margins between the cells, when adding dynamic size.